# how to append the same data to div

Tags: jquery

i would like to add

content to

element each time when i click the button

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>appendTo demo</title>
<style>
#foo {
background: yellow;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>I have nothing more to say... </p>
<button onclick="hamza()"> Click </button>



<script>
function hamza(){
$( "p" ).appendTo("p");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

what i want that when i click the button

content (I have nothing more to say...) added each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this... When the document is ready we find the text in p and set it to a variable. Then when a click occurs we inject that text into p. Hope  tat helps!

Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s9Lawqe/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var par = $("p").text()
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("p").append(par)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>I have nothing more to say... </p>
<button> Click </button>
```

Comment: i don't wont to write <p> in hamza function i need to get this data from html and replicate it by click each time

Comment: I am a little unclear but perhaps this is what you mean [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s9Lawqe/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As the updated question asked, if you want to get the text from the paragraph, do this:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#buttonID").on("click", function(){
        var paragraf = $("#wrapper > p").eq(0).html();
        $("<p>"+paragraf+"</p>").appendTo("#wrapper");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>I have nothing more to say... </p>
</div>
<button id="buttonID"> Click </button>
```

If you are unsure if the tag is `<p>` or something else, this code will support children elements of the wrapper like `<span>`, `<div>` and `<p>`
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/2kvsdhuv/)

Comment: i don't wont to write <p> in hamza function i need to get this data from html and replicate it by click each time

Comment: Aha, then I updated my answer to comply :) By getting the content of `p`, you can copy it as many times you want. If you want the contents of the wrapper, and copy it, it will first copy once, then double each time. Therefore I took a guess that this solution is what you really want.